# Android "application not installed" error on tablet, not on phone

Tags: android

I have scoured the internet for this, but none of the "answers" I have found so far have fixed it for me. My app installs and runs 100% on my phone, which runs Android 4.1.2.  It appears to install ok on my tablet too, which runs Android 4.3.  But when I try to run it on the tablet, I get the "Application is not installed" error.  What is even stranger is that if I run it using the App Manager inside ES File Explorer, it runs fine!

So my suspicion is that Android 4.3 is more strict about something that 4.1.2 lets through.  But what?  I just can't find it.  And why it should run from within ES File Explorer is just weird.  The app manifest is below. I have tried several different values for the target SDK, but nothing makes any difference. The app is signed using the Export Wizard in Eclipse, using a certificate created there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="marshallarts.wordfinder"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.10" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hasCode="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EnterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enter" 

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_play" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would add as a comment but don't have enough rep at the moment.

Have you changed your default launcher activity in your project recently? It could be that the link in your Android Home application is referencing the old activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved this at last. It was (of course) my error - I had not correctly understood how to specify the app's permissions, and had not set them properly in the manifest.  Corrected that, and it now runs happily.  It is still a minor mystery why it ran on my phone - seems to me it should not have - but no matter, I am now on the right track.